# Tool to convert image with text to word or txt or html

Tags: html, .net

Let me know any tool to convert image file with text to word, txt or html...

Comment: @kishh: your question doesn't make much sense I'm afraid...

Comment: Are you looking for Optical Character Recognition (OCR) software/libraries?

Comment: yes i am looking for the same

Comment: if you're trying to read CAPTCHA images, don't.

Answer (score 2):

The technique you're looking for is [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).
Try looking on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=OCR&sbo=kw) for OCR implementations in .NET.